# mso-number-format is not known property. How to get this property?

Tags: jquery, css, excel, ms-office, export-to-excel

I’m using visual studio 2022.I tried to do export to excel so I have change cell format to text. Used this mso-number-format but got this error “not known property” so thought to download this library from Microsoft https://download.microsoft.com/download/a/c/1/ac18e8a2-ce20-41b5-8407-c4cec4a17f19/ofhtml9.exe

Getting 404 error.

Please suggest any idea.

How to get this Css property?
How to convert excel format to text using css property ?

Comment: What code did you try to use? Could you be more specific?

Comment: Html:  <td class="text">@model.versioncode</td> 
 style: td.text{mso-number-format:};
example: versioncode is 099 if i do export to excel this version code then 0 got truncated .

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: why i couldnot get this mso-number-format css property? do we have any alternative css property for number format convertion purpose?

Comment: data:<td>099</td>  button:<button onclick="exportToExcelBase()">ExportToExcel</button>
function exportToExcelBase() {
var htmls = document.getElementById('btable').outerHTML;
    var uri = 'data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,';
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.download = "BaseDetails.xls";
    link.href = uri + htmls;
    link.click();
    link.style.display = "none";
}
Zero got disappear when exporting this data 099 to excel.